# How can I attach a TLS/SSL certificate in a NSURLRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, nsurlrequest

I need to communicate with a server and I need to attach a self signed TLS certificate with every `NSURLRequest`.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection delegate should implement `connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:` and answer YES.  Once that's done, you're delegate will receive `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:`

To proceed with a cert, that method should answer an NSURLCredential.  Create one of those with your certificate using

```
+ (NSURLCredential *)credentialWithIdentity:(SecIdentityRef)identity certificates:(NSArray *)certArray persistence:(NSURLCredentialPersistence)persistence
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can implement `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` (available in iOS 5), then you need only 1 delegate method for authentication instead of 2.

Comment: @MartinR wouldn't this be super easy for a malicious user to patch, override the connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace and answer NO, so the app stops checking the cert like this?

Comment: @Tiago: iOS apps are code signed, it is not that easy to patch them (if possible at all).

Comment: Fair enough, though I'm also thinking on the OSX side, where apps aren't always code signed (since that requires an apple dev license, which isn't mandatory for osx dev).

Comment: Guide link is broken